# Counting Journeys

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I have obtained cyclists journeys poly lines.
I am trying to count number of journeys on each street segment using OSM.
I've split the line using OSM however, I am not sure what is the best way to count the poly lines.

I've used spatial join on ArcMap. I think its joined all intersected lines

[image: The black lines represent cyclist journey, the green lines represent OSM street segments]

[image: After using spatial join and using representing number of counts on each street segment]

Comment: What were the exact parameters of the spatial join operation? What does the second image mean, the desired state or what you got from your spatial join?

Comment: -- I am trying to determine number of trips occur on each street segment.
-- I used Join data function in ArcMap "Each line will be given a summary of the numeric attributes of the lines in the layer" and clicked on "SUM". I think I am having similar problem to https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4537/developer @developer